# How do I properly use a "for loop" to roll one die (or multiple) within a function of another die roll?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm a student and new to computer programing and had a quick question regarding a project I'm working on and how I am suppose to make it work.

This is what the requirement is: Instead of having two dice initially showing on the page, start with only one die image, and build the second image tag inside a for loop in your function. Remove the first block of code (that rolls the first die) and instead put the code for the second die (the one that builds the img tag) into a "for" loop that runs twice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //double dice script
        function SelectImage2() {
            roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            imgName2 = '../images/die' + roll2 + '.gif';
            document.getElementById('dieImg2').src = imgName2;

            roll3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            imgName3 = '../images/die' + roll3 + '.gif';
            document.getElementById('dieImg3').src = imgName3;


        }

    </script>

<div style="text-align:center">
        <p>
            <img id="dieImg2" alt="die image"
            src="../images/die2.gif" >

            <img id="dieImg3" alt="die image"
            src="../images/die3.gif" >
        </p>
        <input type="button" value="Roll until doubles" onclick="SelectImage2();">

    </div>
```

Basically, I guess I'm just looking for someone to maybe explain the for loop function and how I am suppose to call one roll within another roll? Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some research as part of your homework.  Consider starting with something like http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: I would also suggest that OP and anyone considering responding to this question read SO's policy around asking homework questions - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You should check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for for an explanation of the for loop in Javascript.

When you write your solution, consider that in the example code you have (almost) the same code repeated twice - use this as a guide for the structure of your loop.

Comment: Do you know how to declare functions?

Comment: Find the common factors in your code - what's the same? Use that and what changes to repeat twice. Look for what doesn't need to be different, and use that to create the base of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
function SelectImage2() {
    for (var i = 2; i <= 3; ++i) {
        var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
            imgName = '../images/die' + roll + '.gif';
        document.getElementById('dieImg' + i).src = imgName;
    }
}
```

Or, if you want compact code,

```
function SelectImage2() {
    for (var i = 2; i <= 3; ++i) {
        document.getElementById('dieImg' + i).src
           = '../images/die' + ( 1 + Math.random() * 6 | 0 ) + '.gif';
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- Always declae your variables using `var`!
- `number|0` is a simple and fast way to round towards 0